# How to take address of non-static member function to use within QtConcurrent?

Tags: c++, c++11, function-pointers, qtconcurrent

I'm trying to run non-static member function in the other thread. If I go:

```
void *(PortManager::*innerAskPtr)() = &this->innerAsk;
QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::run(innerAskPtr);
```

it prompts that

> ISO C++ forbids taking the adress of an unqualified or parenthesized non-static member function to form a pointer to member function.

but if I delete this extra reference symbol:

```
void *(PortManager::*innerAskPtr)() = this->innerAsk;
QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::run(innerAskPtr);
```

it goes that it

> cannot convert 'PortManager::innerAsk' from type 'void (PortManager::)()' to type 'void* (PortManager::*)()`

What to add on the right side to get these extra stars (*) on the left?

But still, even if I would get there, there is always another error; about the run(T(*)()):

> no matching function for call to 'run(void* (PortManager::*&)())

it's so over my head to understand how this reference got there...

Comment: @MattMcNabb can it be just non-member function which will take pointer to object on which it will operate, as an argument?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for QtConcurrent::run](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html) seems to explain all this.

> Using Member Functions
>
> `QtConcurrent::run()` also accepts pointers to member functions. The first argument must be either a const reference or a pointer to an instance of the class. Passing by const reference is useful when calling const member functions; passing by pointer is useful for calling non-const member functions that modify the instance.

There are code examples immediately following this text.

In your code:

```
void *(PortManager::*innerAskPtr)() = this->innerAsk;
QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::run(innerAskPtr);
```

the error message indicates that `this->innerAsk` returns `void`, but you are trying to assign it to a pointer-to-member-function returning `void *`.   You probably meant:

```
void (PortManager::*innerAskPtr)() = &PortManager::innerAsk;
```

but you don't need to do this in order to call `QtConcurrent::run`, as the code examples show you can just write:

```
QtConcurrent::run( this, &PortManager::innerAsk );
```

Comment: If you still have trouble then it would be helpful to update your post to show the declaration of `innerAsk`

Comment: I did it like this: "void (*staticInnerAskPtr)(PortManager*) = staticInnerAsk; QFuture<void> f = QtConcurrent::run(staticInnerAskPtr, this);" where staticInnerAsk(*) just calls *->innerAsk() but your version removes all the errors too and it's simpler... thank you. :)